# How to remove all chars from an array, leaving it only numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mlp

I'm using sklearn.MLPClassifer and i exported my weights into a txt with this:

```
arr = list(np.array(model.coefs_, dtype = object))
file = open("weightss.txt", "w+")
file.write (str(arr))
file.close()
```

the thing is, the weights arent the same for each[] in model.coefs_, and its exported with "array" and bunch of other character i dont want in it. How do i export only numbers (float type) from this array?

The output i get:

```
array([[ 0.055124  ,  0.04365641, -0.0271139 , ...,  0.02899075,
         -0.14442606, -0.04212195],
        [-0.01849607, -0.01092366,  0.01105672, ..., -0.00383433,
         -0.23810516,  0.03760549],
        [ 0.02357766, -0.04846305,  0.0028944 , ..., -0.00372297,
         -0.23913875,  0.03809774],
        ...,
        [ 0.04734891,  0.00075733,  0.05273402, ...,  0.02994463,
         -0.00568819, -0.05830916],
        [ 0.12168126,  0.06481046,  0.03357674, ..., -0.06854297,
          0.00458801, -0.06863405],
        [ 0.09052689, -0.03500097, -0.06934987, ..., -0.05713005,
         -0.04042818, -0.07102473]])
 array([[ 6.49345111e-01, -2.80867026e+00, -4.47025490e-01,
          5.47926183e-02, -2.32258820e-01,  3.00891945e-01,
         -3.28820315e+00, -1.11907300e+00,  2.13128839e-01,
         -2.60551663e+00,  2.42408007e+00, -1.31142015e+00,
         -7.13036636e-01,  2.98367056e+00,  1.23166718e+00,
          1.84157657e+00,  2.50413248e-01, -6.74166192e-01,
         -1.04169355e-01, -8.85277883e-01],
        [ 3.82943554e-02, -1.3093057
```

and so on...
i want it to be only numbers though, without those ',' and other characters, so i can import it back for it to learn those weights.

Comment: You need to iterate over *arr* and write each element to the output file in whatever format you need

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample input and the desired output.

Comment: Thats what I thought @ArthurKing. Apparently not...

Comment: Did you try to save the whole model directly to a file? You can do this with pickle
```
pkl_filename = "pickle_model.pkl"
with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file)
```

Comment: @AlexandruPlacinta Why would anyone pickle to a text file? Surely the point about a text file is that it's human readable?

Comment: ive edited the post for you to understand more accuratly, sorry if i mislead anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
import os

with open('weightss.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for a in model.coefs_:
        np.savetxt(fp, a, fmt='%f')
        fp.write(os.linesep)
```

Demo:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(2022)
coefs = [np.array(rng.random((4, 5))), np.array(rng.random((5, 1)))]
print(coefs)

# Output
[array([[0.24742606, 0.09299006, 0.61176337, 0.06066207, 0.66103343],
        [0.75515778, 0.1108689 , 0.04305584, 0.41441747, 0.98862926],
        [0.96919869, 0.25697153, 0.55876211, 0.24234798, 0.32202029],
        [0.89135975, 0.94611366, 0.72253931, 0.92847437, 0.99608701]]),
 array([[0.2494223 ],
        [0.06229007],
        [0.94479027],
        [0.65028587],
        [0.32167568]])]
```

Content of `weightss.txt`:

```
0.247426 0.092990 0.611763 0.060662 0.661033
0.755158 0.110869 0.043056 0.414417 0.988629
0.969199 0.256972 0.558762 0.242348 0.322020
0.891360 0.946114 0.722539 0.928474 0.996087

0.249422
0.062290
0.944790
0.650286
0.321676
```

Comment: Kind of, It does work, just need to know how to import it as a float but thats another problem which does not relate. This works, thank you so much